# Mad Libs program

Tags: python, game, template, tkinter

My code creates a Mad Libs program. Its a prewritten story that you fill in blindly. There are 4 pages of 7 entry boxs and labels. When the inputs are in and next is pressed it saves inputs as variables that it puts in the story and changes the labels. When all blanks have been written in. An info box pops up with the story. Back is a wip as i can't figure out how to insert text into an entry box in a function.
Is there any way I could reduce the code yet work just as efficiently? Also, is there anything I could add to make the experience more convenient like adding helpful buttons or function?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()
root.title("Mad Libs: Action Movie")

x = 0



#para is the paragraph %s is variable
Para = '''%s is a normal %s. Then, one day, a %s explodes, causing a %s to blow up, and a nearby %s erupts into a %s of flames.%s realizes that he's being chased by the government, who's trying to %s him. While on the run, he teams up with an incredibly attractive woman named %s, who has an incredible %s. She may be from the streets, but she can %s like nobody's buisness. The duo decide to turn tables on their pursuers by blowing up a %s, which triggers a chain reaction, causing the local %s, %s, and %s to explode. Then, the bad guys' helicopter gets %s by a piece of %s from when the %s exploded, and the helicopter explodes and falls onto a %s, causing it to %s, which shoots a fireball straight into the heart of %s and destroys the bad guy leader. Everything is %s and the two decide that such a %s ordeal has caused them to fall in %s with each other. They decide to celebrate by %s on the %s,and they even managed to use a %s from the beginning of the movie, to %s the whole story together.'''

l1 = Label(root, text="Man's Name")
l1.pack(side='top', fill='none', expand=False, padx=0, pady=4)#padx and pady change button location

e1 = Entry(root)
e1.pack(side='top', fill='none', expand=False, padx=1, pady=4)#labels and entry boxs

l2 = Label(root, text="Occupation")
l2.pack(side='top', fill='none', expand=False, padx=4, pady=4)

e2 = Entry(root)
e2.pack(side='top', fill='none', expand=False, padx=5, pady=4)

l3 = Label(root, text="Noun")
l3.pack(side='top', fill='none', expand=False, padx=8, pady=4)

e3 = Entry(root)
e3.pack(side='top', fill='none', expand=False, padx=9, pady=4)


l4 = Label(root, text="Noun")
l4.pack(side='top', fill='none', expand=False, padx=12, pady=4)

e4 = Entry(root)
e4.pack(side='top', fill='none', expand=False, padx=13, pady=4)

l5 = Label(root, text="Noun")
l5.pack(side='top', fill='none', expand=False, padx=16, pady=4)

e5 = Entry(root)
e5.pack(side='top', fill='none', expand=False, padx=17, pady=4)

l6 = Label(root, text="Shape")
l6.pack(side='top', fill='none', expand=False, padx=20, pady=4)

e6 = Entry(root)
e6.pack(side='top', fill='none', expand=False, padx=21, pady=4)

l7 = Label(root, text="Man's Name")
l7.pack(side='top', fill='none', expand=False, padx=24, pady=8)

e7 = Entry(root)
e7.pack(side='top', fill='none', expand=False, padx=25, pady=4)

root.geometry('500x500')


LN = Label(root, text="1 of 4")
LN.pack(side='bottom', fill='none', expand=False, padx=20, pady=4)

MN1 = ' '#defining variables
O1 = ' '
N1 = ' '
N2 = ' '
N3 = ' '
S1 = ' '
MN2 = ' '
V1 = ' '
WN1 = ' '
BP1 = ' '
V2 = ' '
N4 = ' '
N5 = ' '
RN1 = ' '
HM1 = ' '
V3 = ' '
N6 = ' '
N7 = ' '
N8 = ' '
V4 = ' '
N9 = ' '
A1 = ' '
A2 = ' '
E1 = ' '
V5 = ' '
N10 = ' '
N11 = ' '
V6 = ' '


def Next():
    global x
    global MN1
    global O1 
    global N1
    global N2
    global N3
    global S1
    global MN2
    global V1
    global WN1
    global BP1
    global V2
    global N4
    global N5
    global RN1
    global HM1
    global V3
    global N6
    global N7
    global N8
    global V4
    global N9
    global A1
    global A2
    global E1
    global V5
    global N10
    global N11
    global V6

    x = x

    if x == 0:
        l1["text"]="Verb"#7 changes text
        l2["text"]="Woman's Name"#8
        l3["text"]="Body Part"#9
        l4["text"]="Verb"#10
        l5["text"]="Noun"#11
        l6["text"]="Noun"#12
        l7["text"]="Restaurant Name"#13
        MN1 = e1.get()#saves previous variable
        O1 = e2.get()
        N1 = e3.get()
        N2 = e4.get()
        N3 = e5.get()
        S1 = e6.get()
        MN2 = e7.get()
        LN["text"]="2 of 4"
        Bck.pack(side='left')

    elif x == 1:
        l1["text"]="Historic Monument"#14
        l2["text"]="Verb Ending In ED"#15
        l3["text"]="Noun"#16
        l4["text"]="Noun"#17
        l5["text"]="Noun"#18
        l6["text"]="Verb"#19
        l7["text"]="Noun"#20
        V1 = e1.get()
        WN1 = e2.get()
        BP1 = e3.get()
        V2 = e4.get()
        N4 = e5.get()
        N5 = e6.get()
        RN1 = e7.get()
        LN["text"]="3 of 4"

    else:
        l1["text"]="Adjective"#21
        l2["text"]="Adjective"#22
        l3["text"]="Emotion"#23
        l4["text"]="Verb Ending In Ing"#24
        l5["text"]="Noun"#25
        l6["text"]="Noun"#26
        l7["text"]="Verb"#27    
        HM1 = e1.get()
        V3 = e2.get()
        N6 = e3.get()
        N7 = e4.get()
        N8 = e5.get()
        V4 = e6.get()
        N9 = e7.get()
        LN["text"]="4 of 4"
        Nxt.configure(text='Submit', command=Submit)# changes next to make it Submit when at end







    root.update()
    e1.delete(0, END)#clears input
    e2.delete(0, END)
    e3.delete(0, END)
    e4.delete(0, END)
    e5.delete(0, END)
    e6.delete(0, END)
    e7.delete(0, END)

    if x <= 3:#stops variable from increasing tooo far
        x = x+1

x = x#restates x as the value that next has increased it to

def Back():
    global x
    global MN1
    global O1 
    global N1
    global N2
    global N3
    global S1
    global MN2
    global V1
    global WN1
    global BP1
    global V2
    global N4
    global N5
    global RN1
    global HM1
    global V3
    global N6
    global N7
    global N8
    global V4
    global N9
    global A1
    global A2
    global E1
    global V5
    global N10
    global N11
    global V6

    x = x



    if x == 1:
        l1["text"]="Man's Name"#7 changes text only since variables will be changed by next
        l2["text"]="Occupation"#8
        l3["text"]="Noun"#9
        l4["text"]="Noun"#10
        l5["text"]="Noun"#11
        l6["text"]="Shape"#12
        l7["text"]="Man's Name"#13
        LN["text"]="1 of 4"
        Bck.pack_forget()

    elif x == 2:
        l1["text"]="Verb"#7
        l2["text"]="Woman's Name"#8
        l3["text"]="Body Part"#9
        l4["text"]="Verb"#10
        l5["text"]="Noun"#11
        l6["text"]="Noun"#12
        l7["text"]="Restaurant Name"#13
        LN["text"]="2 of 4"

    elif x == 3:
        l1["text"]="Historic Monument"#14
        l2["text"]="Verb Ending In ED"#15
        l3["text"]="Noun"#16
        l4["text"]="Noun"#17
        l5["text"]="Noun"#18
        l6["text"]="Verb"#19
        l7["text"]="Noun"#20
        LN["text"]="3 of 4"

    else:
        pass
    root.update()
    Nxt.configure(text='Next', command=Next)# just in case Next is Submit

    if x >= 1:# stops back from going toooo low
        x = x-1

    e1.delete(0, END)
    e2.delete(0, END)
    e3.delete(0, END)
    e4.delete(0, END)
    e5.delete(0, END)
    e6.delete(0, END)
    e7.delete(0, END)



def Submit():
    global Para
    global A1
    global A2
    global E1
    global V5
    global N10
    global N11
    global V6

    x = x
    A1 = e1.get()#gets final variables
    A2 = e2.get()
    E1 = e3.get()
    V5 = e4.get()
    N10 = e5.get()
    N11 = e6.get()
    V6 = e7.get() 
    #takes Para and fills in %s with variables chronologicaly
    messagebox.showinfo("Story", Para % (MN1, O1, N1, N2, N3, S1, MN2, V1, WN1, BP1, V2, N4, N5, RN1, HM1, V3, N6, N7, N8, V4, N9, A1, A2, E1, V5, N10, N11, V6))
    root.update()





Nxt = Button(root, text="Next", command=Next)#buttons
Nxt.pack(side='right')
Bck = Button(root, text="Back", command=Back)
Bck.pack(side='left')
Bck.pack_forget()






root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'make the experience more convenient'?

Comment: Basically like insert previously entered text when back is hit or another button to restart or something like that.

Comment: This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. [Questions should include a description of what the code does](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1226)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Redundancy: the second line is completely unnecessary. Your first `import` already imports *everything* of the `tkinter` module, including `messagebox`.
2. Clarity: I suggest to put every widget and function/method in a class like this:

   ```
   class GUI():

       def __init__(self, master):

           self.master = master # root
           self.master.title("Mad Libs: Action Movie")

           self.x = 0
           self.Para = '''%s is a normal %s. Then, one day, a %s explodes,
           causing a %s to blow up, and a nearby %s erupts into a %s of
           flames.%s realizes that he's being chased by the government,
           who's trying to %s him. While on the run, he teams up with an
           incredibly attractive woman named %s, who has an incredible %s.
           She may be from the streets, but she can %s like nobody's
           buisness. The duo decide to turn tables on their pursuers by
           blowing up a %s, which triggers a chain reaction, causing the
           local %s, %s, and %s to explode. Then, the bad guys' helicopter
           gets %s by a piece of %s from when the %s exploded, and the
           helicopter explodes and falls onto a %s, causing it to %s, which
           shoots a fireball straight into the heart of %s and destroys the
           bad guy leader. Everything is %s and the two decide that such a
           %s ordeal has caused them to fall in %s with each other. They
           decide to celebrate by %s on the %s,and they even managed to use
           a %s from the beginning of the movie, to %s the whole story
           together.'''

           self.l1 = Label(self.master, text="Man's Name")
           self.l1.pack(side='top', fill='none', expand=False, padx=0, pady=4) #padx and pady change button location

           self.e1 = Entry(self.master)
           self.e1.pack(side='top', fill='none', expand=False, padx=1, pady=4) #labels and entry boxs

           self.l2 = Label(self.master, text="Occupation")
           self.l2.pack(side='top', fill='none', expand=False, padx=4, pady=4)

           self.e2 = Entry(self.master)
           self.e2.pack(side='top', fill='none', expand=False, padx=5, pady=4)

           self.l3 = Label(self.master, text="Noun")
           self.l3.pack(side='top', fill='none', expand=False, padx=8, pady=4)

           self.e3 = Entry(self.master)
           self.e3.pack(side='top', fill='none', expand=False, padx=9, pady=4)


           self.l4 = Label(self.master, text="Noun")
           self.l4.pack(side='top', fill='none', expand=False, padx=12, pady=4)

           self.e4 = Entry(self.master)
           self.e4.pack(side='top', fill='none', expand=False, padx=13, pady=4)

           self.l5 = Label(self.master, text="Noun")
           self.l5.pack(side='top', fill='none', expand=False, padx=16, pady=4)

           self.e5 = Entry(self.master)
           self.e5.pack(side='top', fill='none', expand=False, padx=17, pady=4)

           self.l6 = Label(self.master, text="Shape")
           self.l6.pack(side='top', fill='none', expand=False, padx=20, pady=4)

           selfe6 = Entry(self.master)
           self.e6.pack(side='top', fill='none', expand=False, padx=21, pady=4)

           self.l7 = Label(self.master, text="Man's Name")
           self.l7.pack(side='top', fill='none', expand=False, padx=24, pady=8)

           self.e7 = Entry(self.master)
           self.e7.pack(side='top', fill='none', expand=False, padx=25, pady=4)

           self.master.geometry('500x500')


           self.LN = Label(self.master, text="1 of 4")
           self.LN.pack(side='bottom', fill='none', expand=False, padx=20, pady=4)

           self.MN1 = ' ' #defining variables
           self.O1 = ' '
           self.N1 = ' '
           self.N2 = ' '
           self.N3 = ' '
           self.S1 = ' '
           self.MN2 = ' '
           self.V1 = ' '
           self.WN1 = ' '
           self.BP1 = ' '
           self.V2 = ' '
           self.N4 = ' '
           self.N5 = ' '
           self.RN1 = ' '
           self.HM1 = ' '
           self.V3 = ' '
           self.N6 = ' '
           self.N7 = ' '
           self.N8 = ' '
           self.V4 = ' '
           self.N9 = ' '
           self.A1 = ' '
           self.A2 = ' '
           self.E1 = ' '
           self.V5 = ' '
           self.N10 = ' '
           self.N11 = ' '
           self.V6 = ' '

           self.Nxt = Button(self.master, text="Next", command=self.Next) #buttons
           self.Nxt.pack(side='right')
           self.Bck = Button(self.master, text="Back", command=self.Back)
           self.Bck.pack(side='left')
           self.Bck.pack_forget()

       def Next(self):

           if self.x == 0:
               self.l1["text"]="Verb" #7 changes text
               self.l2["text"]="Woman's Name" #8
               self.l3["text"]="Body Part" #9
               self.l4["text"]="Verb" #10
               self.l5["text"]="Noun" #11
               self.l6["text"]="Noun" #12
               self.l7["text"]="Restaurant Name" #13
               self.MN1 = self.e1.get() #saves previous variable
               self.O1 = self.e2.get()
               self.N1 = self.e3.get()
               self.N2 = self.e4.get()
               self.N3 = self.e5.get()
               self.S1 = self.e6.get()
               self.MN2 = self.e7.get()
               self.LN["text"]="2 of 4"
               self.Bck.pack(side='left')

           elif self.x == 1:
               self.l1["text"]="Historic Monument" #14
               self.l2["text"]="Verb Ending In ED" #15
               self.l3["text"]="Noun" #16
               self.l4["text"]="Noun" #17
               self.l5["text"]="Noun" #18
               self.l6["text"]="Verb" #19
               self.l7["text"]="Noun" #20
               self.V1 = self.e1.get()
               self.WN1 = self.e2.get()
               self.BP1 = self.e3.get()
               self.V2 = self.e4.get()
               self.N4 = self.e5.get()
               self.N5 = self.e6.get()
               self.RN1 = self.e7.get()
               self.LN["text"]="3 of 4"

           else:
               self.l1["text"]="Adjective" #21
               self.l2["text"]="Adjective" #22
               self.l3["text"]="Emotion" #23
               self.l4["text"]="Verb Ending In Ing" #24
               self.l5["text"]="Noun" #25
               self.l6["text"]="Noun" #26
               self.l7["text"]="Verb" #27    
               self.HM1 = self.e1.get()
               self.V3 = self.e2.get()
               self.N6 = self.e3.get()
               self.N7 = self.e4.get()
               self.N8 = self.e5.get()
               self.V4 = self.e6.get()
               self.N9 = self.e7.get()
               self.LN["text"]="4 of 4"
               self.Nxt.configure(text='Submit', command=Submit) # changes next to make it Submit when at end

           self.master.update()
           self.e1.delete(0, END) #clears input
           self.e2.delete(0, END)
           self.e3.delete(0, END)
           self.e4.delete(0, END)
           self.e5.delete(0, END)
           self.e6.delete(0, END)
           self.e7.delete(0, END)

           if self.x <= 3: #stops variable from increasing tooo far
               self.x = self.x+1 # better: self.x += 1

       def Back(self):

           if self.x == 1:
               self.l1["text"] = "Man's Name" #7 changes text only since variables will be changed by next
               self.l2["text"]="Occupation" #8
               self.l3["text"]="Noun" #9
               self.l4["text"]="Noun" #10
               self.l5["text"]="Noun" #11
               self.l6["text"]="Shape" #12
               self.l7["text"]="Man's Name" #13
               self.LN["text"]="1 of 4"
               self.Bck.pack_forget()

           elif self.x == 2:
               self.l1["text"]="Verb" #7
               self.l2["text"]="Woman's Name" #8
               self.l3["text"]="Body Part" #9
               self.l4["text"]="Verb" #10
               self.l5["text"]="Noun" #11
               self.l6["text"]="Noun" #12
               self.l7["text"]="Restaurant Name" #13
               self.LN["text"]="2 of 4"

           elif self.x == 3:
               self.l1["text"]="Historic Monument" #14
               self.l2["text"]="Verb Ending In ED" #15
               self.l3["text"]="Noun" #16
               self.l4["text"]="Noun" #17
               self.l5["text"]="Noun" #18
               self.l6["text"]="Verb" #19
               self.l7["text"]="Noun" #20
               self.LN["text"]="3 of 4"

           else:
               pass
           self.master.update()
           self.Nxt.configure(text='Next', command=Next) # just in case Next is Submit

           if self.x >= 1: # stops back from going toooo low
               self.x = self.x-1 # better: self.x -= 1

           self.e1.delete(0, END)
           self.e2.delete(0, END)
           self.e3.delete(0, END)
           self.e4.delete(0, END)
           self.e5.delete(0, END)
           self.e6.delete(0, END)
           self.e7.delete(0, END)

       def Submit(self):

           self.A1 = self.e1.get() #gets final variables
           self.A2 = self.e2.get()
           self.E1 = self.e3.get()
           self.V5 = self.e4.get()
           self.N10 = self.e5.get()
           self.N11 = self.e6.get()
           self.V6 = self.e7.get() 
           #takes Para and fills in %s with variables chronologicaly
           messagebox.showinfo("Story", Para % (MN1, O1, N1, N2, N3, S1, MN2, V1, WN1, BP1, V2, N4, N5, RN1, HM1, V3, N6, N7, N8, V4, N9, A1, A2, E1, V5, N10, N11, V6))
           self.master.update()
   ```
3. Create a `main` function (like in C and C++ programs):

   ```
   def main():

       root = Tk()
       app = GUI(root) # app.master and root are synonyms now
       app.master.mainloop() # You also often see root.mainloop(), but in my opinion this is clearer
   ```
4. Call the `main` function in an `if`-statement (that's necessary if you want to import this file in another Python script without running the `main` function:

   ```
   if __name__ == '__main__':

       main()
   ```
5. Don't stop improving your code. There are probably still a lot more things to do better (such as giving your variables self-explaining names).